# How to initialize the Invitation dialog (not the apprequest one)?

Tags: facebook, dialog, invitation

There are a lot of applications that use an Invitation dialog, like this one here:

[image: Invitation dialog]

However I find no documentation or a single topic describing this specific dialog. It is not the same as the apprequest dialog which is mostly referred to as the 'invitation dialog'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That dialog is built with the FBML API. [A good example can be found here](http://facebook-developer.net/2008/02/20/allow-your-users-to-invite-their-friends/). However this API is in process of deprecating.

With the new JavaScript SDK you can initialize an application invitation, using the [Request Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/).

Comment: sorry, balexandre, but this does not answer my question. I'm quite aware of the Request dialog you're talking about. The dialog from above is not automatic and is triggered by an application (in this case Gardens Of Time, and can be also seen in many other apps). Plus, this post is already on Facebook stackoverflow.

Comment: Then you really missing the point, what are you asking is a simple request. Facebook will make that an invitation, that's why you don't see `Invitation` SDK, cause it's simple an app request. To help you more, show what you have accomplish so far so we can guide you, we are not code-generator-forum!

Comment: No, it's not. The apprequest dialog does not show request preview like this one. Take a look at the apprequest dialog and this one (in Gardens of Time), and you'll see the difference.

Comment: Oh, so this is the FBML approach, which is in process of deprecating. Strangely, the new apprequest dialog does not distinguish apprequest from appinvitation. I like the FBML version most. Please edit your answer with the note that this is FBML, not apprequest.

Comment: in my answer "SDK" means fbml, as I named the other as Javascript API :)

Comment: @balexandre: Questions posted on Facebook Stack Overflow also show up on vanilla Stack Overflow. It's just a tag filter of sorts, not an independent Stack Exchange 2.0 site.